# Is it possible to add different classes to all elements in html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I was trying to add different classes in all elements in HTML document or HTML output when page is in WordPress. I would be easier to edit and style code if all elements would have different classes.
I know that you can select classes via parent class in CSS, but if some class has several

elements inside, it is hard to select only one of them and when you work in WordPress it's not user friendly to change theme code.

So, my question is: **Is it possible to add different classes to all elements?** I would try add class function in jQuery and select $(body *) and add some loop, but then classes would not be fixed to elements and if I add new code, classes would change every time on document load with new code, and CSS style would affect different elements.
I know it's not possible for HTML without any database, but it would be great if this is possible for WordPress.

Comment: What is the intention behind this?

Comment: what is your mean exactly? you want to add a class for all of elements in your page?

Comment: yes, I have around 10 sites a day which need some changes, and I taught it would save time if I put script in header, and in developement tools find class and add style to it without changing code and finding classes. Sometimes in plugins like woocommerce is not easy to find certain page template, and some elements are generated by sripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body *').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('special-class-' + i);
});
```

This would add a class special-class-0 to the first element, special-class-1 to the second and so on.
That said, I suggest you change the theme's code and add the classes you need. I don't understand why you say it's not "user friendly". The users won't even know you changed the theme's code.

Comment: +1 css is the proper way to do this. Add ids to individual elements you want to change, add additional classes to groups of objects to change, etc.

Comment: Sorry, wrong expression, my fault. I taught user friendly for me, not for users of sites i develop. It takes tame to find classes I need in some "bigger" sites.
If I add classes that way will they stay fixed to the element? When I add few elements, for example below <body> tag, wouldn't last element on page change class for few "i" values?

Comment: Yes it would. But trust me, this is gonna be a maintainability nightmare. Take your time and modify the theme's source